# Moment Ito's Process Proof

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, itos-lemma, sde

I have a following stochastic integral - related problem that I have difficulty to solve:

Given 
\begin{equation}
dX_t = -\alpha X_tdt+\sigma\sqrt{X_t}dW_t
\end{equation}

and the second moment of $X_t$ is denoted by $m^{(2)}_t=\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)$.

Can you prove that $m^{(2)}_t$ has the following expression: 
\begin{equation}
m^{(2)}_t=\frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha}X_0\exp(-\alpha t)+(X^2_0-\frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha}X_0)\exp(-2\alpha t)
\end{equation}

I can give you the expression of $d(X_t^2)$ just to save some time:
\begin{equation}
d(X_t^2)=-2\alpha X^2_t dt+2\sigma X_t\sqrt{X_t} dWt+\sigma^2 X_t dt
\end{equation}

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another way**
\begin{equation}
X_t^2=X_0^2-2\alpha \int_{0}^{t}X^2_s ds+2\sigma\int_0^t X_s\sqrt{X_s} dW_s+\sigma^2\int_{0}^{t} X_s ds
\end{equation}
thus
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]=X_0^2-2\alpha\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{E}[X^2_s] ds+\sigma^2\int_{0}^{t} \mathbb{E}[X_s] ds$$
As you saw in the first answer, 
$\mathbb{E}[X_s]=X_0^2e^{-\alpha s}$,
thus
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]=X_0^2-2\alpha\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{E}[X^2_s] ds-\frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha}X_0^2\left(e^{-\alpha t}-1\right) $$

Set $m(t)=\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]$, we have
$$m(t)=X_0^2-2\alpha \int_0^t m(s)ds-\frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha}X_0\left(e^{-\alpha t}-1\right)$$
Take differentiate with respect to time,
$$m'(t)=-2\alpha\,m(t)+\sigma^2 X_0\,e^{-\alpha t}$$
In other words
$$m'(t)+2\alpha\,m(t)=\sigma^2 X_0\,e^{-\alpha t}$$
This ODE is a First-order equation ,
$$\mu(t)=e^{\int {2\alpha } dt}=e^{2\alpha t}$$
and 
$$m(t)=\frac{1}{e^ {2\alpha t}}\left(\sigma^2 X_0 \int e^ {2\alpha t}e^ {-\alpha t}dt+c\right)$$
where $c$ is a constant, we have
$$m(t)=e^ {-2\alpha t}\left(\frac{\sigma^2 X_0}{\alpha}e^{\alpha t} +c\right)$$
on the other hand $m(0)=X_0^2$ and $m(0)=\frac{\sigma^2 X_0}{\alpha}$, therefor $c=X_0^2-\frac{\sigma^2 X_0}{\alpha}$. Finall we have
$$m(t)=\frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha}X_0e^{-\alpha t}+\left(X^2_0-\frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha}X_0\right)e^{-2\alpha t}$$

Comment: @Donkey_JOHN I solved this question again . Two methods are correct.

Comment: No problem, clear and sound! Thank you for your help! @BehrouzMaleki

Comment: Please. good luck

Answer (score 3):

Set $f(t,x)=xe^{\alpha t}\in\mathbb{C}\left([0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\right)$. By application of Ito's lemma, we have
$$d\left(X_te^{\alpha t}\right)=\alpha e^{\alpha t}X_t dt+e^{\alpha t}dX_t +\underbrace{d[e^{\alpha t},X_t]}_{0}\tag 1$$
thus
$$d\left(X_te^{\alpha t}\right)=\sigma e^{\alpha t}\sqrt{X_t}dW_t\,. \tag 2$$
By Integration on $[0,t]$, we have
$$X_te^{\alpha t}=X_0+\sigma \int_{0}^{t}e^{\alpha s}\sqrt{X_s}dW_s \tag 3$$
therefore
$$X_t=X_0e^{-\alpha t}+\sigma \int_{0}^{t}e^{-\alpha (t-s)}\sqrt{X_s}dW_s \, .\tag 4$$
Now calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_t]$ and $\text{Var}(X_t)$ and apply
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]=\text{Var}(X_t)+\mathbb{E}[X_t]^2\tag 6$$
**Note**
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t]=X_0e^{-\alpha t}\tag 7$$
 and
$$\text{Var}(X_t)=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sigma \int_{0}^{t}e^{-\alpha (t-s)}\sqrt{X_s}dW_s\right)^2\right]=\sigma^2 \int_{0}^{t}e^{-2\alpha (t-s)}\mathbb{E}\left[X_s\right]ds\tag 8$$
therefore
$$\text{Var}(X_t)=\frac{X_0\sigma^2}{\alpha}(e^{-\alpha t}-e^{-2\alpha t})+X_0^2e^{-2\alpha t}\tag 9$$
**More details**
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]=\text{Var}(X_t)+\mathbb{E}[X_t]^2=\frac{X_0\sigma^2}{\alpha}(e^{-\alpha t}-e^{-2\alpha t})+X_0^2e^{-2\alpha t}+X_0^2e^{-2\alpha t}\tag{10}$$
then
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]=\frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha}X_0e^{-\alpha t}+(X^2_0-\frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha}X_0)e^{-2\alpha t}\tag{11}$$

Comment: In equation $8$ I use the Ito's isometry formula. See it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry

Comment: Hi can you solve the problem without solving $X_t$?

Comment: Hi . No, because we need $\mathbb{E}[X_t]$

Comment: Solve the integral in equation 8 and insert the result to equation 6

Comment: The dynamic of the $m^{(2)}_t$ can be expressed as follow: 
$dm^{(2)}_t=-2\alpha m^{(2)}_t+\sigma^2 m^{(1)}_t$, could you solve directly with this? since you have the expression of $m^{(1)}$

Comment: As some time you are not able to have the explicit expression of the process, we need alternative way of calculating the MGF. Many thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50653/discussion-between-donkey-john-and-behrouz-maleki).